# Microsoft Graph API Add "Error while adding group as a member to other group"

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting an error when adding a group as a member of other group using the Microsoft Graph API. It was working okay before, but now it's giving me an error.

I am using this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
body:
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "An invalid operation was included in the following modified references: 'members'.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-09-08T16:09:31",
        "request-id": "b1f3a1d9-96ae-4f3e-9ec0-73781bed4379",
        "client-request-id": "b1f3a1d9-96ae-4f3e-9ec0-73781bed4379"
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What type of group are you trying to add a member to and what type of group are you trying to add as a member. Dos this error happen for other groups in your tenant or just one combination? Asking because as per [Add Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), there are some constrains on certain group types.

Comment: Trying to add Security group as a member to security group. I am only using this combination. @Danstan

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. I can add SGs as members of other SGs. You may need to cross check the group types then try with different combinations and create a support request because if it persists as it may be specific to your tenant.

Comment: @Danstan I am using ADB2C is that possible in ADB2C to add group as a member to group?